# Why is this query for 1400 entities taking 1.5 seconds?

Tags: go, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a GAE app using datastore. It's a very low traffic app (~1 request/s or less).

The datastore isn't huge, maybe 300MB total, but again, low number of read/writes per second.

Yet, read speeds are atrocious. If I do:

```
q := datastore.NewQuery("Sale")
var sales []IndividualSale
keys, err := client.GetAll(ctx, q, &sales)
```

It takes 1.5 *seconds* to simply return all entities of "Sale" kind - and there are only ~1400 total! 1.5 seconds to return 1400 entities (each entity has ~10 properties) is abysmal performance.

How can I speed this up? I am using `"cloud.google.com/go/datastore"` (not the legacy appengine module which I hear is faster, but deprecated) along with golang `1.15`.

Does this seem right? Do I need to add it to `index.yaml` (I thought that was only if your query needed access to specific properties?).

Edit:

Latency is both observed in Chrome Devtools (where request takes anywhere from 1-1.5 seconds to complete) as well as from log statements:

```
q := datastore.NewQuery("Sale")
var sales []IndividualSale
start := time.Now()
keys, err := client.GetAll(ctx, q, &sales)
log.Debug("Took ", time.Since(start)) // Prints "Took 1.320244586s"
```

Edit2: Here's a Cloud Trace of the problematic query:

[image]

Comment: I wonder if this is limited to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40454958/google-cloud-datastore-slow-800ms-with-simple-query-from-compute-engine?

Comment: A simple pair of VMs with postgres will run circles around Google DataStore. Just saying...

Comment: You should be able to use cloud trace (https://cloud.google.com/trace) to check if there is issue running the query or with setting up the connection.  How are you observing the latency in chrome with a Go query?

Comment: @JimMorrison Thanks - I didn't realize datastore had built in telemetry. I'm going to try enabling it with: https://opencensus.io/integrations/google_cloud/google_cloud_datastore/go/

Comment: @JimMorrison - nice insight, I can confirm the latency from cloud console as well. I posted an image to the question